# Scala factorial function answer not what it should be

Tags: scala, recursion, factorial

I am studying for an exam and I'm confused as to why I am getting 24 for a result when calling 4 to the function.

```
scala> def fact(n:Int):Int = if (n<2) 1 else n*fact(n-1)
fact: (n: Int)Int

scala> fact(4)
res0: Int = 24
```

If I'm right, shouldn't the answer be

```
(4) * fact(4-1) = 12 ?
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nope it should be 24 according to that function

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why? @smac89

Comment: `if (4<2) 1 else 4 * (if (3 < 2) 1 else 3 * (if (2 < 2) 1 else 2 * (if (1 < 2) 1))) -> 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based solely on the poster's conceptual error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you code does exactly the right thing. It is always a good idea to define some test cases - input -> expected output:

0! = 1

1! = 1

2! = 2*1! = 2

3! = 3*2! = 6

4! = 4*3! = 4*6 = 24